# Adding CSS class to image in lightbox

Tags: wordpress, lightbox

I already display some images in lightbox. Works perfect.

But I have a special case. Some images that open in lightbox should get an additional class to add them a css :after.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Thorsten

Comment: Please, provide more information(jsfiddle , HTML, css and etc).

Comment: The easiest way should be i give an url where I want to change it.

[link]http://gansdoll.de/#produkte

If you click on of the product images the :after class is already added.

[link]http://gansdoll.de/#zubereitung

In this image the :after class shouldn't be shown.

Comment: Have you passed your class name to [mainclass option](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#mainclass)?

Comment: Prbolem is, that I can't get in touch with the mainclass because the theme only provides adding a css class to the wrapping element and not the mfp himself.

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not get it. Can you explain more? Which element do you want to add a class?

Comment: I want to add the class to the opened lightbox-image.